# Title is eaten by diff in suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

While reviewing a [suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/76794), I encountered something weird: a title is deleted and no title is inserted in the diff as can be seen below.

[image: suggested edit screenshot]
When I press the "improve" button, I see exactly the same (unmodified) title. This happens both when I use the review tool and when I go to the question page and press the "edit" link.

This is the HTML for that title:

```
<h2>
                                <a class="question-hyperlink" href="/questions/248051/difficult-network-configuration"><span class="diff-delete">Difficult network configuration</span></a>
                    </h2>
```

I see the edit has been approved and there is no visible change in the title which make it even more confusing.

Comment: Thanks that is useful, can you post that as answer? It would also be nice if a moderator adds the status-completed tag to this Q.

Comment: You're right, that should've been an answer. I've made it one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a Meta Stack Overflow question about this:

- [Suggested edit that only changes tags, also shows the title as removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165216/suggested-edit-that-only-changes-tags-also-shows-the-title-as-removed)

[As reported in balpha's answer, it seems the bug was recently fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165228/185080); the fix will be effective when the next build is rolled out. (I don't know how long that takes but past experience indicates it's not very long.)

Comment: It was rolled out about an hour later.